# Using Datatype as value in Dictonary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have this structure - here in a dummy implementation :

```
interface IBasicWaveform
{
    double FindAmplitudeFactor(int samplesPerSecond);
    double ValueAtPhase(double phase);
}

abstract class BaseWaveform : IBasicWaveform
{
    public double FindAmplitudeFactor(int samplesPerSecond)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public double ValueAtPhase(double phase)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

sealed class SawDownWaveform : BaseWaveform
{
}

sealed class SawUpWaveform : BaseWaveform
{
}
```

I would like to create a `Dictionary` with a Description (a String) and a BaseWaveform DATA TYPE as TValue

So I would like to write code like this:

```
    var myDict = new Dictionary<string,  BaseWaveform**Datatype** >()
    {
        {"Saw down", SawDownWaveform},
        {"Saw up", SawUpWaveform}
    }
```

I've also tried this:

```
    var myDict = new Dictionary<string, Type>()    
    {
        {"Saw down", (Type)SawDownWaveform},
        {"Saw up", (Type)SawUpWaveform}
    };
```

But it gives me a compile error:

> 'WindowsFormsApplication5.SawDownWaveform' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

The question is: how can I do this in c#?

Comment: what is wrong with `Dictionary<string,  BaseWaveform>` ?

Comment: You want to use typeof(SawDownWaveform), instead of static casting.

Comment: @Selman22 the fact that it is a instance, and not what I needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `typeof` operator is how you get a `Type` object when given a type identifier at compile time:

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, Type>()    
{
    {"Saw down", typeof(SawDownWaveform)},
    {"Saw up", typeof(SawUpWaveform)}
};
```

Comment: Thank you  Servy. That was the thing I was missing. Can I restrict it to at type of BaseWaveform. (I'll accept your answer as soon as I can)

Comment: @JensBorrisholt Not statically.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're just looking to use the `typeof()` operator where instead you have an attempted cast to `(Type)`.

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, Type>()    
{
    {"Saw down", typeof(SawDownWaveform)},
    {"Saw up", typeof(SawUpWaveform)}
};
```